# How to get Page Content from Http Url Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried this below code but it return null data..Please help me to how to get data from url using javascript

```
function makeHttpObject() {
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); }
    catch (error) { }
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
    catch (error) { }
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    catch (error) { }

    throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
}

var request = makeHttpObject();
request.open("GET", "Http URL", true);


var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "Http URL", true );
    xmlHttp.send();
   xmlHttp.responseText;


request.send();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4)
        alert(request.responseText);
};
```

Comment: I'd assume you run into problems with the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I am new to javascript please help me..

Comment: Check the answer below. In short: you can not retrieve the content from other pages within a webpage. There are some exceptions, but those require control of the other server, where you want to fetch pages from.

Comment: I want to fetch data from weburls

Comment: In general this can not be done in the browser without the use of plugins/extensions or control over the server you want to fetch from. Another option would be to fetch the other pages on your server, which is possible.

Comment: But my code returns null data..

Comment: And probably an error on the console ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86788/discussion-between-devi-prasad-and-sirko).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your browser's JavaScript console is open.  It can be opened with the `F12` key in most browsers.  It will tell you if the code you are trying to run is violating your browser's CORS policy.  CORS stands for Cross Origin Resource Sharing, and since a strict policy is typically in place by default in most browsers, you cannot make a request to another website that is not under the same domain as the one making a request.

For example, if I were running code on www.example.com and wanted to do an AJAX request to www.example2.com, it would not work because www.example.com is the originating domain and for security reasons you cannot make requests to www.example2.com-- they are different domains.

You can get around this by disabling security on your browser (here's [how to do it in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/425533)).  But be aware that your website visitors WILL have security enabled, so please do not design your code to require this major security hole to be exposed.

Comment: then how to fetch data from any weburl in java script

Comment: @DeviPrasad You cannot do it in JavaScript without disabling CORS security in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter problems with CORS. Simply put, CORS is a mechanism to prevent exploits on the client-side caused by malicious javascript.

If you can, I'd recommend [enabling CORS server side](http://enable-cors.org/server.html). That means that you have access to the backend of the server you are retrieving the data from.

If you don't have access to the server you want to retrieve the data from, then you need to do it at another level. For example in PHP a basic methos is with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

Comment: I don't know of any way to make it in JavaScript for all visitors without enabling CORS on the server where you would get the data from. Maybe with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.2/api/http.html#http.request), but that is if you are using Node.js on your server.